# Facebook export api request status is always SCHEDULED

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried the facebook analytics_app_events_exports graph api. 
I got the id as response and checked the status for 3-4 hours. Still the status is SCHEDULED.

The documentation says schedule will change to RUNNING and then to COMPLETED within 2 hours which in my case didn't happen.

Any insights on this to how to proceed with this? Any forum or dev support where I can raise this request?

Answer (score 0):

The status was updated as completed after 2 days. I believe heavy traffic must be the reason for the delay